# Create DropDown list for jira custom field in REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, jira

I'm trying to retrieve the available options for fields through the Jira REST API but I'm getting stuck on the custom fields.

A normal field returns something like this:

```
{[priority, {
  "required": false,
  "schema": {
    "type": "priority",
    "system": "priority"
  },
  "name": "Priority",
  "key": "priority",
  "hasDefaultValue": true,
  "operations": [
    "set"
  ],
  "allowedValues": [
    {
      "self": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/1",
      "iconUrl": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/highest.svg",
      "name": "Highest",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "self": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/2",
      "iconUrl": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/high.svg",
      "name": "High",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "self": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3",
      "iconUrl": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
      "name": "Medium",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "self": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/4",
      "iconUrl": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/low.svg",
      "name": "Low",
      "id": "4"
    },
    {
      "self": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/5",
      "iconUrl": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/lowest.svg",
      "name": "Lowest",
      "id": "5"
    }
  ],
  "defaultValue": {
    "self": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3",
    "iconUrl": "https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
    "name": "Medium",
    "id": "3"
  }
}]}
```

The custom fields on the other hand return a much "smaller" set!

"Sprint" Custom Field:

```
 {[customfield_10113, {
      "required": false,
      "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string",
        "custom": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-sprint",
        "customId": 10113
      },
      "name": "Sprint",
      "key": "customfield_10113",
      "hasDefaultValue": false,
      "operations": [
        "set"
      ]
    }]}
```

"Epic Link"

```
{[customfield_10006, {
  "required": false,
  "schema": {
    "type": "any",
    "custom": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-epic-link",
    "customId": 10006
  },
  "name": "Epic Link",
  "key": "customfield_10006",
  "hasDefaultValue": false,
  "operations": [
    "set"
  ]
}]}
```

As you can see there are no options available, but i know that there are.
How can I get to these values through rest?

I have tried checking the request that the cloud server makes but it's pretty different for each of the custom fields and i cannot find a relation between them. For example:

To get the sprint possible values: https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprint/picker?query=

and to get the Epic values: https://inn-inw.atlassian.net/rest/greenhopper/1.0/epics

I'm trying to make things as clean as possible and I would prefer not to hard code the request, specially because i would probably need to update the code every time a new custom field is created.

PS: I have tried some of the solutions presented in other questions but couldn't find one that fits what i need. eg: https://inn-inw.atlassian.net//rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=PROJKEY&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields returns only the short description that is displayed above.